# Class that depends on its closure

Tags: javascript

Because of angular factories, I am thinking about using a class that uses some methods that are on its closure as if they were private methods.

This is not 100% classical inheritance nor revealing pattern, so I'm not sure if this is correct or not. Here is a small example:

```
myClass = (function() {
    function privateMethod (stuff) { return something }
    function TheClass () { this.someValue = 'Hello'}
    TheClass.prototype.someMethod = function () { return privateMethod(this.someValue)}
    return TheClass
}());
```

And then do something like

```
instance = new myClass()
```

I think this works fine for helper functions or private methods that do not change the values of the instantiated object. Using private "variables" may be useful for singelton classes or maybe fixed values.

Is there any problem with this implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's typically fine to do and its essential that most classes depend on their closure. Usually your class will be in its own file - its own module. If you are using a module loader (I hope you are), then closure is already implied and the methods are already "private" when defined like this:

```
// Begin MyClass.js
function privateMethod (stuff) { return something }
function TheClass () { this.someValue = 'Hello'}
TheClass.prototype.someMethod = function () { return privateMethod(this.someValue)}

// depending on which module loader you are using
return TheClass;
module.exports = TheClass;
export default TheClass;
```

Comment: On this particular case I'm using angular factories, so I think we can consider it as a module loader. But even If I do not, I think this implementation will be fine for just functions. What about using internal variables? I made some test and internal objects will be shared across all instances. Will this happen with primitives too?

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you are asking - but I consider it a crucial feature of JavaScript that you can have closures and "hidden" variables. For example, you could keep a private array that keeps track of every instance of your class, or a private object which stores the responses of AJAX requests. All instances could (and should) have access to these. Any variable defined within that closure is shared. But remember, primitives are passed by value whereas object properties are passed by reference. That's a separate discussion. Google it.